# Testing to see if a word contains only specified syllables

Tags: python

I need to test if a word only contains certain syllables. For example if a word, "pikakapichu" contains only the syllables, "pi", "ka", or "chu", I want to return "Yes". If it contains other syllables or characters then I want to return "No".

Another example:

word= "pikapikachudo"

Returns: "NO" because it has a syllable other than 'pi', 'ka', and 'chu'

Comment: How do you decide which letters are part of which syllable? Wouldn't "pik, ach, u" be just as valid?

Comment: Hi Andrea, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic so that your questions will be on the topic.

And please update the question regarding "what already you try" even it just a pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be describing a phonology where each syllable is open and the nucleus vowel is always preceded by a cluster of consonants. (With some additions which I hope are unimportant here, Japanese is a language with this structure.) Thus you can use a regular expression like

```
[bcdfghj-np-tvwxz]+[aeiou]
```

to describe each syllable.

Comment: I was thinking of a brute force `len(re.sub('pi|ka|chu', '', 'pikakapichu'))` but your answer is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the `syllables` in a list, and going through that list and replace every item in the list with an empty string.

- Eg: Take `pi` and replace `pi'` with empty string inside l. Output should "`pikapikachudo` --> `kakachudo`

same process to the other items.

"`pikapikachudo` --> `kakachudo`  --> `do`

At the end, we test if `l` is empty or no. If it's empty, it means that these are the only sylabules in the word `l`

```
l= "pikapikachudo"

r= [ 'pi', 'ka','chu']


def isOnlysyllables_in_word(l,r):
    for x in r:
        l= l.replace(x, '')
    print "You still have <",l,"> in word"
    return l==''

print isOnlysyllables_in_word(l,r) #return False
```